# Preventing adult filter issues on shared domain

Tags: filter, subdomain

Our application provides hosted blogs and galleries for photographers. Many of these sites are hosted on a shared domain, each with their own subdomain.

We have noticed some of our clients post adult photography on their sites. Do we need to be concerned about the entire domain being flagged for adult content by search engines and/or internet filters?  Are there important things to do to make sure our more family-friendly sites aren't blocked? Do we need to segregate the adult sites onto a different IP entirely?

I assume similarly-structured sites such as Tumblr have had to address this issue.